# VSCode "Some content has been disabled in this document"

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I linked a scripts.js file correctly to an HTML document in VScode trying to get a button to execute the script correctly. But instead of displaying the alert I would like, the live preview displays the words "Some content has been disabled in this document". I'm not sure what to do about this situation.

[image]

I expected an alert to pop up in live preview

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead replace it with a text-based [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display video and audio in HTML preview in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696877/how-to-display-video-and-audio-in-html-preview-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: So seems like you need to first add an event listener to the button. After that you want to set the content of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Live preview doesn't seem to be able to show alerts, but there is a extension in vscode that runs your webpage in the browser. Link: [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)

To activate it, go to the bottom right of your screen and press on `Go Live`. The file that you were veiwing will open up in your browser.

[image]